# How to use different toolbar for different fragments in a single activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My application has an activity with a navigation drawer (with drawer layout). For each navigation item, different fragments are loading. I want to use different toolbar for different fragments (one with parallax effect and one normal toolbar), both should be collapsible. Is it possible ?

Comment: Use toolbar in fragment's xml instead of activities xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can do it.
Use `toolbar` in `fragment` instead of `activity` so you can get what you want.

you wanna parallax effect in one `fragment` so just add `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in that fragment, note one thing for parallax effect you need to use `coordinateLayout` as a parent in your fragment then only you will get your result.

Comment: Does this solution work with navigation drawer ? I am using navigation drawer in mainactivity

Comment: @Vipin Mundayad How did you reattach the toolbars to the navigation drawer?

Comment: how do you handle fragment navigation[Back press in case of fragments] having their own toolbars?